# Finding out where requests are generated

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have an application I don't thoroughly know and I have to make some bugfixes.
On one point, we use primefaces remote commands, to initialize a backing bean and some other objects to display what we want.

This remoteCommand (which has the autoRun=true attribute) or respectively the action called by the remoteCommand, is called twice when I enter the site. In the next steps, everything runs fine, but at the first call, the action is called twice, and I don't know why. This is a problem, because in the first run, we can encounter expected errors and want to display them, but on the second call of the method, the facesMessage is discarded and not shown to the user.

I think, somewhere in this application (There is a lot going on in the navigation logic) another request is made and the container, where my remoteCommand is embedded, is refreshed twice, but I don't know for sure and I don't know where. I checked that the remoteCommand is not in the container I refresh with this command.

My question is, is there some kind of possibility to find out where requests are fired in my application? A more efficient way than analysing each line of code?

Comment: In modern webbrowsers you can put breakpoints in JavaScript code and inspect the call/variables stack, like as you can do in a Java IDE.

Comment: in firefox you find very helpfull developer tools: debugger, ...etc, try network analysing tool, and select XHR, so you can filter only XHR requests ...etc.